# Magento 2: Is there a way to import more than 200 products at a time?

Tags: magento2, import-products

My import is only addressing the first 200 parts, is there somewhere to change this setting?

I am using the built in import function

My inventory is 8870 lines but it only is importing the first 200.

Is this a limitation that is set somewhere?  I see people mentioning importing much more than this but I cannot find where a setting might be.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can import the first 200 Products. You need to Export that Products in csv and Select 200 Products in CSV and delete others.

Then import that CSV file using Magento import Module.

`Settings>import >upload` csv file

Comment: So are you saying the only way to do it is 200 lines at a time?

Comment: The question is asking how to import more than 200 products in 1 CSV. The goal is to import 8870 products without breaking the CSV into many CSVs.

Comment: I have not speicified number of rows in csv file. You can add as many as you can save in csv file.